# merge values inside array of objects with the same key-value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following array:

```
     const arr = [  
   {  
      id:"aaa",
      name:"aaa",
      type:"director",
      nodes:[  
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"111",
            name:"111"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      id:"aaa",
      name:"bbb",
      type:"director",
      nodes:[  
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"222",
            name:"222"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      id:"aaa",
      name:"aaa",
      type:"director",
      nodes:[  
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"333",
            name:"333"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      id:"aaa",
      name:"bbb",
      type:"director",
      nodes:[  
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"444",
            name:"444"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

desired output:

```
        const arr = [  
   {  
      id:"aaa",
      name:"aaa",
      type:"director",
      nodes:[  
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"111",
            name:"111"
         },
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"333",
            name:"333"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      id:"aaa",
      name:"bbb",
      type:"director",
      nodes:[  
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"222",
            name:"222"
         },
         {  
            type:"manager",
            id:"444",
            name:"444"
         }
      ]
   }
```

I am trying to merge the value of the array of objects of nodes that have the same key-value(id, name, and type) pairs in the above array to the desired output.

I have tried the following but in vain with the arr.reduce, but in vain:

```
arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
      var existEl = acc.find(e => e.nodes.id === el.nodes.id);
      if (existEl) {   
        existEl = el;
      } else {
        acc.push(el);
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The format of your arrays is invalid,.. (p.s.: Sorry for the edit, I rolled it back , was accidental)

Comment: By "the same key-value pairs" do you mean specifically `id`, `name`, and `type`, or "everything-but-`nodes`", or something else altogether?

Comment: yes. I just edited the question

Comment: I think you can manage that using a for in/as loop function... something like this pseudo-code: for obj in array  for(i=0;i<newArr.length;i++) if(newArr[i].name == obj.name -add them, else -newArr[]=obj

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all items with same `id` and `name`

```js
var array = [{ id: "aaa", name: "aaa", type: "director", nodes: [{ type: "manager", id: "111", name: "111" }] }, { id: "aaa", name: "bbb", type: "director", nodes: [{ type: "manager", id: "222", name: "222" }] }, { id: "aaa", name: "aaa", type: "director", nodes: [{ type: "manager", id: "333", name: "333" }] }, { id: "aaa", name: "bbb", type: "director", nodes: [{ type: "manager", id: "444", name: "444" }] }],
    result = [...array.reduce((m, o) => {
        var key = ['id', 'name'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        if (m.has(key)) {
            m.get(key).nodes.push(...o.nodes);
        } else {
            m.set(key, Object.assign({}, o, { nodes: o.nodes }));
        }
        return m;
    }, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```